# Display 2 or more places on the same map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map where I want to display 2 places: departure and arrival. I have no problem when I display the first place, but when I have to display the second, I can't do the mean with the two coords. Here is the code.

```
                // options for the map of departure only
                if (coord_arrival == "")
                {
                    // replacing the previously saved with the new coordinates
                    if (place.geometry.viewport)
                        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
                    else {
                        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                        map.setZoom(17); // why 17? because it looks good
                    }
                    coord_departure = place.geometry.location;
                    // HERE IS THE PROBLEM: I can't do anything on this string. Why?
                    coord_departure = coord_departure.replace("(", "");
                    alert("coordinates of departure: " + coord_departure);
                    // the output will be something like: "(coordX, coordY)"
                }
```

If you need it, I will paste the code for the mean of 2 coordinates also. Thank You

Comment: Can you please post a link to your code? It's hard to tell what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably trying to manipulate a non-string object as string with `replace`.

The output `(x, y)` is probably a value returned from the object's `toString` method which is used for its serialization triggered by the `+` operator.

You can call the method yourself and alter the result.

```
coord_departure = coord_departure.toString().replace(/\(|\)/g, '');
```